# Error : Could not display "obex://" when paired with a Nokia 3110c

Tags: bluetooth, file-sharing

I have paired my nokia 3110c via bt on my pc, I can receive a file from my pc to the phone, but I can not browse the contents of phone from my computer. Here is the error message

```
Error: Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.
Please select another viewer and try again.
```

How can I transfer contents from my phone to my computer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved the problem, or rather say found the reason behind the problem.

The main reason behind this problem was battery level,

(Guess) if the battery level reaches below some point, the device doesn't recognize or process the request sent by the machine and can not send proper reply to machine. That can be the reason why we can not access the file system.

We have also tried one samsung phone, and a sony Erickson phone with low battery (in each case more than 60% battery is drained) and got same result.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you will need to debug `obex-data-server`.

You can install `qt4-dev-tools`, launch `qdbusviewer` and search for "obex" in the session bus. If it doesn't find anything, launch `obex-data-server` from terminal. Then you will see `org.openobex` point and will be able to play with some of its methods.