# "Alternate browser" to have Bluez/Blueman support browsing files in a mobile

Tags: 16.04, bluetooth, transfer, bluez, blueman

### Situation

Using Ubuntu 16.04

I managed to activate the connection between a desktop computer and a Nokia 206 (with Bluetooth standard 2.1 EDR) mobile via a Bluetooth dongle.

Please take note:

- The hardware side looks fine.
- Sending **individual files** to the mobile works as expected.
- Sending **individual files** from the mobile works as expected.
- It is the **capability of file browsing from the computer into the mobile** that misses out.

### Issue

I then make steps towards browsing the files on the mobile. 
It starts off well with a progress bar completing its swipe, but at the next step I get the message

> Failed to launch default browser
>   The specified location is not supported
>   You can enter an alternate browser in **service settings**

### Research

I found an earlier mention of this issue in [Ubuntu 16.04 iPhone iOs 10 Bluetooth Devices not allowing Browse function](https://askubuntu.com/questions/856477/ubuntu-16-04-iphone-ios-10-bluetooth-devices-not-allowing-browse-function) (2016)

From the Blueman project https://github.com/blueman-project/blueman/wiki/Integrations#obex-file-transfer I found

> blueman can use a file browser for browsing files on a remote device. The command for this can be **customized in the local services settings**.
>    Most file browsers provide this OBEX FTP support using gvfs which in terms makes use of obex-data-server. 
>   This works only with **BlueZ 4** and was thus removed from gvfs completely in version **1.23.92**.
>   **blueman 2.1** will drop support for browsing files.
>   [last edited 2016]

Now: I have Bluez **5.37**, gvfs **1.28.2**, Blueman **2.0.4**.
Even though I cannot rely on gvfs, support for browsing should be still there -- see [Blueman project changelog](https://github.com/blueman-project/blueman/blob/a456b17496c9c751983a7252c9d0aadda253bc51/CHANGELOG.md).

I found out the window Local Services down Bluetooth Devices:

[image]

### Questions

**Question 1** What could I set in the advanced options to activate the **alternate browser**?

**Question 2** If none, are there alternatives to Blueman/Bluez for receiving files in the computer instead of sending them from the mobile one by one?

======================================

### Appendix on libraries

This is the snapshot of the Synaptic search on the theme **bluez**, the tools to manage Bluetooth devices for linux:

[image: synpatic and bluez]

Regarding **obex** that is [OBject EXchange protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OBject_EXchange)

[image: synaptic and obex]

None of the obex-related tips in

- [Ubuntu 17.04 Sending/Receiving files by Bluetooth not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/921462/ubuntu-17-04-sending-receiving-files-by-bluetooth-not-working)
- [Error : Could not display "obex://" when paired with a Nokia 3110c](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25702/error-could-not-display-obex-when-paired-with-a-nokia-3110c?rq=1)

helped